# How to convert 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' to 'System.Drawing.Image'?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, c#-4.0, bitmapimage

I would like to convert my `BitmapImage` to a `System.Drawing.Image`?

This is my `BitmapImage`:

```
BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(someString, UriKind.Absolute));
```

Now, how would i create a `System.Drawing.Image` from my `bmi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN has a very good sample for interop between `BitmapImage` and `System.Drawing.Image` - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rwlodarc/archive/2007/01/03/wpf-bitmapsource-and-gdi-bitmap-interop.aspx

Comment: Hey, i took a look at the examples but couldn't find the answer on the question above. Could someone post a little snippet of what you have to do?